# What happens when you return a promise inside an async function?

Tags: javascript

As I understand it, an async function always returns a Promise, which resolves when the function returns, or rejects if an error is thrown.

What happens if an async function returns a Promise on its own? How should this be handled when calling the download() function below?

```
const download = async () => {
    const res = await axios({
        "...",
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'stream'
    });

    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(absoluteArchivePath);
    res.data.pipe(writer);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        writer.on('finish', () => resolve());
        writer.on('error', () => reject());
    })
}
```

Comment: ...nothing exceptional happens. Promises automatically flatten so returning an explicit promise just becomes the sole value returned, you never have "promise within a promise". So the consumer still gets a single level promise that either gets resolved or rejected. Only in this case you have more control over that (other than using plain `return` or `throw`).

Comment: You handle it like any other async function. Like `download().then(() => ).catch(error=>error)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

> The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of
> an asynchronous operation and its resulting value.

```
const myAsyncFunction = error => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (error) {
      reject('an error occured');
    } else {
      resolve('OK');
    }
  });
};

myAsyncFunction(true)
  .then(r => {
    console.log('ok');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('error');
  });
// log: error

myAsyncFunction(false)
  .then(r => {
    console.log('ok');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('error');
  });
// log: ok
```